# "command 'bracket-pair-color-dlw.run' not found" appears in VS Code whenever I press number 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, brackets

"command 'bracket-pair-color-dlw.run' not found" appears in VS Code whenever I press number 1.
the number 1 is located above alphabet q in my keyboard.
I've connected another keyboard and it gives out the same message.

I already uninstalled all the bracket related extensions in VS Code and also in my local directory folders.

Below are the error I got by pressing "1".

```
2023-05-18 08:26:31.066 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal 'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-05-18 08:26:31.403 [error] Extension 'tabnine.tabnine-vscode' wants API proposal 'inlineCompletions' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned. 2023-05-18 08:26:31.416 [warning] [twxs.cmake]: 'cmake.cmakePath() + + ЯLICH. 01 2 0101 01 MLICH.2023-05-18 08:26:34.520 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 51ms
2023-05-18 08:26:35.824 [error] [Extension Host] (node:8228) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.(Use Code --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
2023-05-18 08:27:11.527 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal
'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-05-18 08:27:11.753 [error] Extension 'tabnine.tabnine-vscode' wants API proposal 'inlineCompletions' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-05-18 08:27:11.764 [warning] [twxs.cmake]: 'cmake.cmakePath' (€) 8€* + *SLICH. 01 42 010I SO ŠLICH.
2023-05-18 08:27:13.641 [error] [Extension Host] (node:10324) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) 2023-05-18 08:27:14.618 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 20ms`
```

```
2023-05-18 09:21:59.310 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2023-05-18 09:21:59.310 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving 1
2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched bracket-pair-color-dlw.run, when: no when condition, source: user. 2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: Received keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Digit1, keyCode: 49, key: 1
2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [], code: Digit1, keyCode: 22 ('1')
2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving 1
2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched bracket-pair-color-dlw.run, when: no when condition, source: user. 2023-05-18 09:21:59.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command bracket-pair-color-dlw.run.
```

Comment: bracket pair coloring is now buildin to VSC, remove all bracket pair coloring extensions

Comment: use keyboard debug to find why `1` call `bracket-pair-color-dlw.run`, uninstalling an extension does not remove a possible key bind

Comment: Thx. I fixed it by deleting by going in the options menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your troubleshooting output is showing that a corresponding command is bound at the user level. check your keybindings.json (`Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in command palette). did you intend to make that keybinding? If not, then remove it from your keybindings.json.